# How to Insert Rows to Table Object Inside an Excel Sheet?

Tags: c#, windows, excel, ado.net

I have difficulties trying to insert rows into an existing table object. Here is my code snippet:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @"C:\myExcelFile.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=False;HDR=Yes;\"";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    string insertQuery = String.Format("Insert into [{0}$] (ID, Title,NTV_DB, Type ) values(7959, 8,'e','Type1')", TabDisplayName);
    cmd.CommandText = insertQuery;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd = null;
    conn.Close();
}
```

As a result I get my rows inserted below a ready-made table object:

[image]

I've also tried inserting data inside a table object like so:

```
 string insertQuery = String.Format("Insert into [{0}$].[MyTable] (ID, Title,NTV_DB, Type ) values(7959, 8,'e','Type1')", TabDisplayName);
```

But I get an error:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'MyTable'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'MyTable' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

As you can see, table with a name `MyTable` does exist. I would be very grateful if someone can shed some light on this mystery.

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Does the table always have empty rows at the end?

Comment: Your table name doesn't have a space at the end of the name like "MyTable "? Just a thought...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB` provider, then be aware that it doesn't support a named range. You need to provide the name of the sheet `[Sheet1$]` or the name of the sheet followed by the range `[Sheet1$A1:P7928]`.
If the range is not provided, it will then define the table as the used range, which may contains empty rows.

One way to deal with empty rows would be to delete them, but the driver doesn't support the `DELETE` operation.

Another way is to first count the number of rows with a non empty `Id` and then use the result to define the range of the table for the `INSERT` statement:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    conn.Open();

    string SheetName = "Sheet1";
    string TableRange = "A1:P{0}";

    // count the number of non empty rows
    using (var cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(null, conn)) {
        cmd1.CommandText = String.Format(
          "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [{0}$] WHERE ID IS NOT NULL;"
          , SheetName);

        TableRange = string.Format(TableRange, (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar() + 1);
    }

    // insert a new record
    using (var cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(null, conn)) {
        cmd2.CommandText = String.Format(
            "INSERT INTO [{0}${1}] (ID, Title, NTV_DB, Type) VALUES(7959, 8,'e','Type1');"
            , SheetName, TableRange);

        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you suggest to deal with the empty rows? it's not really a problem. The real problem is how to insert the rows within the Table object

Answer (score 2):

If you execute this code:

```
var contents = new DataTable();
using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("Select * From [{0}$]", TabDisplayName), conn))
{
    adapter.Fill(contents);
}
Console.WriteLine(contents.Rows.Count);//7938
```

you will see 7938 (last row number on your screenshot). And when you insert new row, it inserted at 7939 position. Empty content in (7929, 7930, ...) rows are ignored, because excel knows that last number is 7938.

Solutions:

1. You must delete all rows after 7928 in excel file.
2. You must insert on specific position.

Comment: Thank you very much, Dmitry. I will try your solution soon and tell you if it worked

Comment: I'm not sure if I can insert data at a specific row. Do you have a sample code you can include in the answer?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure Access C# works the same as Excel, but this worked on a spreadsheet for me. Maybe it could help you?

```
Table3.ListRows[1].Range.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
```

Comment: The question asks for an ADO.NET solution

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
private void GetExcelSheets(string FilePath, string Extension, string isHDR)
{
string conStr="";
switch (Extension)
{
    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
        conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                 .ConnectionString;
        break;
    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
        conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                 .ConnectionString;
        break;
}

//Get the Sheets in Excel WorkBoo
conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
connExcel.Open();

//Bind the Sheets to DropDownList
ddlSheets.Items.Clear(); 
ddlSheets.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Sheet--", ""));    
ddlSheets.DataSource=connExcel
         .GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
ddlSheets.DataTextField = "TABLE_NAME";
ddlSheets.DataValueField = "TABLE_NAME";
ddlSheets.DataBind();
connExcel.Close();
txtTable.Text = "";
lblFileName.Text = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
Panel2.Visible = true;
Panel1.Visible = false;
}
```