# Insert Record at the top of Excel

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, oledb, script-task

Hi I have this C# code and it is working well:

```
string fileFullPath = Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileFullPath"].Value.ToString();

            //Create Excel Connection
            ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=NO\";";
            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);

            //Get Sheet Name
            cnn.Open();
            DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
            {
                if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$"))
                {
                    if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("Survey"))
                    {
                        sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();



                        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                        string sql = null;


                        myCommand.Connection = cnn;
                        sql = "Insert into [" + sheetname + "] values('5','e')";
                        myCommand.CommandText = sql;
                        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cnn.Close();
                    }

                }
            }
```

But this code inserts the record at the end of the excel file and what I need to do is insert that record at the first row (A1:B1)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the range beside the Sheet Name:

```
sql = "Insert into [" + sheetname + "A1:B1] values('5','e')"
```

More additional information can be found in the following question:

- [How to Insert Rows to Table Object Inside an Excel Sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554279/how-to-insert-rows-to-table-object-inside-an-excel-sheet)
- [How do I write to specific cells in Excel? ... C#, OleDb](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2a560ba3-d70b-442e-b684-231582d971e3/how-do-i-write-to-specific-cells-in-excel-c-oledb?forum=exceldev)

If you are looking for some detailed article on performing SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE operations on EXCEL using OLEDB refer to:

- [Read and Write Excel Documents Using OLEDB](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB)
- [READ WRITE EXCEL FILE WITH OLEDB IN C# (WITHOUT INTEROP)](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/9014/read-write-excel-file-with-oledb-in-c-without-interop)